# Plot with LabelingFunction and condition

Tags: plotting, labeling

How can I apply a `LabelingFunction` with an if else condition? 
Suppose you have the following plot:

```
BarChart[{4, 3, 2, 1}, BarOrigin -> Left, LabelingFunction ->(Placed[#,Left] &)]
```

[image]

I want to plot it with the first two labels justified as they currently are (left), and the third and fourth label in bold and justified to the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to always read the "Details" section of a symbol's documentation: [`LabelingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingFunction.html).  There is it explained how to compute the label based on the element's index rather than its value:

> `LabelingFunction->f` specifies that each chart element should have a label given by `f[value,index,lbls]`, where `value` is the data value associated with the element, `index` is its position in the nested list of datasets, and `lbls` is the list of relevant labels.

To understand better what is being passed to the function, simply display all values in the label:

```
BarChart[data, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[{##}, Left] &)]
```

[image]

Now that we understand the structure of indices better, we can write our labelling function appropriately:

```
BarChart[data, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 LabelingFunction -> 
  Function[{value, index, label}, 
   If[Last[index] > 2, 
    Placed[Style[value, Bold], Right], 
    Placed[value, Left]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
BarChart[{4, 3, 2, 1}, BarOrigin -> Left,LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, If[# <= 2, Left, Right]] &)]
```

will answer your question! Bold might be realized similar...